# IdentityServer4 adding IdentityClaim

Tags: identityserver4

In IdentityServer4 sample in config.cs you have code to add [Client, IdentityResources, etc](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/master/Quickstarts/Combined_AspId_and_EFStorage/src/IdentityServer/Config.cs), I want to know how I can add IdentityClaims also. Because only find option to add Clients, IdentityResources, ApiResources only. Can anyone point me in right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you are probably looking for a new `IdentityResource` to encapsulate some sort of custom identity claim type that your users could have. An example of that below:

```
return new List<IdentityResource>
{
    //..Your other configured identity resources

    new IdentityResource(
    name: "custom.name",
    displayName: "Custom Name",
    claimTypes: new[] { "custom.name" });
};
```

Then you can add that as a user claim:

```
        new TestUser
        {
            SubjectId = "1",
            Username = "alice",
            Password = "password",

            Claims = new []
            {
                new Claim("custom.name", "SomeCustomNameValue")
            }
        },
```

Comment: The scenerio is we add IdentityServer4.EntityFramework to enable support for EntityFramework and SQL Server. Now, with the sample code mentioned above, we get a seeddata.cs which add records to IdentityResources, Clients, ApiResources table. With that I want to add IdentityClaims data also to the table. How I can do that in seeddata.cs for example (or any other way).
PS: The IdentityServer has a IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Storage project which includes all the details and I want to utilize it and extend it, how I can do that.

Comment: @Khuzema You should ask a separate question about that where you can provide samples, work you have done so far and issues you’re having because it is out of scope of your current question.